# Unexpected sign error when creating a list

Tags: r, list, unexpected-token

I am trying to create a color list for specific levels of two factors. The parameters are the following:

```
> df.coldata
        Condition  Tank
R235      Control    T6
R236  LowExposure    T6
R239 HighExposure    T6
R241      Control    T8
R242  LowExposure    T8
R245 HighExposure    T8
R247      Control T14_3
R248  LowExposure T14_3
R250 HighExposure T14_3
```

As I don't want to manually fill in the Tank numbers or Condition I was trying to create a list using assigned variables like this:

```
### Specify colors ####
Tanks <- levels(df.coldata$Tank)
Conditions <- levels(df.coldata$Condition)

ann_colors <- list(
  Condition = c(Conditions[1]="lightskyblue", # This doenst work ... BUGS here!!!
                Conditions[3]="royalblue1",
                Conditions[2]="navyblue"),
  Tank = c(Tanks[1]="gray90",
           Tanks[2]="gray65",
           Tanks[3]="gray40")
)
```

But this creates an error telling me:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"ann_colors <- list(
  Condition = c(Conditions[1]="
```

When I run the code with:

```
ann_colors <- list(
  Condition = c(Control="lightskyblue",
                LowExposure="royalblue1",
                HighExposure="navyblue"),
  Tank = c(T14_3="gray90",
           T6="gray65",
           T8="gray40")
)
```

it works like a charm. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use *setNames* instead:

```
ann_colors <- list(
  Condition = setNames(c("lightskyblue", "royalblue1", "navyblue"), Conditions),
  Tank = setNames(c("gray90", "gray65", "gray40"), Tanks)
  )
```

The reason your code errors is that we are trying to assign a new value to *Conditions/Tanks* within `c()`. Below would work, and will replace the 1st value of *Conditions* to `"lightskyblue"`, but this is **not** what we want:

```
Conditions[1] = "lightskyblue"
Conditions
# [1] "lightskyblue" "HighExposure" "LowExposure"
```

And wrapping it in `c()` throws the error:

```
c(Conditions[1] = "lightskyblue")
# Error: unexpected '=' in "c(Conditions[1] ="
```

Comment: thx a lot! This works beautifully. I just changed the order of the vectors in Conditions accordingly with ```Conditions <- Conditions[c(1,3,2)]``` and now it works perfect. Thx for the explanation as well. Now I even understand my mistake ;)